# find() a value of an ajax response(HTML)?(javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've been working on developing a web program(javascript) which can grab specific data from a web page(form) and make a statistic pie chart.

I called jQuery API to Get the html content and find specific "td" and "tr" data from the received html. However the html content is large, I found the response was cut off, the response only showed half part of the html.

Here's the code of my program:

```
    function Requestdata() {
      jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'https://example.com/test.html',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8'
        },
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (data) {
          var Htmlresponse = data;
          //debugging code to preview responded html with alert
          alert(Htmlresponse);


          jQuery(Htmlresponse).find('table#ServerUpTime tr').each(function (i, tr) {
          jQuerythis = jQuery(this);
          //find server name value
          var ServerName = jQuerythis.find("td:first-child font").text();
          //find server status
          var ServerUporDown = jQuerythis.find("td:last-child font").text();
          console.log(ServerName);
          console.log(ServerUporDown);
          });

        }
      });
    }
```

After testing, I found `alert(Htmlresponse);` only gave me half part of the html, it did not contain the full html,the rest part was cut off,some of the data I tried to request was missing too. As a result, my rest code did not work because it tried to find specific "tr" "td" from an invalid html.

***Edit: After I changed my debugging code from `Alert();` to `console.log` I found the error was actually happened at**

```
jQuery(Htmlresponse).find('table#ServerUpTime tr').each(function (i, tr) {
              jQuerythis = jQuery(this);
              //find server name value
              var ServerName = jQuerythis.find("td:first-child font").text();
              //find server status
              var ServerUporDown = jQuerythis.find("td:last-child font").text();
              console.log(ServerName);
              console.log(ServerUporDown);
              });
```

I was trying to use above code to find values from this html example:

```
<html>
<body>
<table id=ServerUpTime>
<tr>
    <td>
        <font>Ubuntu Serverno1</font>
    </td>
    <td>
        <font>ping:156</font>
    </td>
    <td>
        <font>Up</font>
    </td>
<tr/>
<tr>
    <td>
        <font>Ubuntu Serverno2</font>
    </td>
    <td>
        <font>ping:632</font>
    </td>
    <td>
        <font>Up</font>
    </td>
<tr/>
</body>
</html>
```

These two lines wasn't executed (not even show an undefined value with firebug),I really have no idea.

```
console.log(ServerName);
console.log(ServerUporDown);
```

I should get "Ubuntu Serverno1 up" and Ubuntu Server2 up" from console.log, but console.log wasn't executed. maybe there's an error in my code? weired that I did not receive any error

Comment: Try `console.log(Htmlresponse);` and open your browser console. also can you give an example of  what should return from the ajax call? thank you.

Comment: `jquery(Htmlresponse)` should be `jQuery(Htmlresponse)`

Comment: There's probably a limit on the size of an `alert()` popup, but that shouldn't affect the rest of the code that processes the result.

Comment: @NewToJS Thank you, I found that console.log of ajax response did return  the full html, the problem was because javascript alert has the content length limit. I should use console.log not alert();,lol.

Comment: @LynchChen Correct. `console.log();` is better for debugging. Some people using `alter();` for testing small things when feeling too lazy to open the browser console but I do recommend sticking with `console.log();` also you're very welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is `jquery(Htmlresponse)` should be `jQuery(Htmlresponse)`. `alert()` will be called. A `ReferenceError` will be thrown at next line

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jquery is not defined
```

https://jsfiddle.net/o5g38dkc/ , https://jsfiddle.net/o5g38dkc/1/

Comment: thank you :) I've found this typing error. But seems like I still have an error at jQuery(Htmlresponse).find('table#ServerUpTime tr')

Comment: I've updated the question, seems like console.log(ServerName);
console.log(ServerUporDown); was not executed without any reason. not even showing an undefined value.

Comment: @LynchChen Missing closing `</table>` tag at `html` `document`. Also, jQuery is removing `<html>` and `<body>` tags from response, returning only `table#ServerUpTime`. Use `jQuery(Htmlresponse).find('tr').each()` https://jsfiddle.net/o5g38dkc/4/

Comment: Thank you @guest271314,it's correct, I appreciate your high quality answer :)

Answer (score 0):

`alert()` is showing a limited length of characters from a string. Your response have probably exceeded that length.